# Получение координат svg при анимации

Tags: javascript, html5, svg, svg-animation

Есть такая анимация в `SVG`:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('star_path').getBBox());
}, 200);
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 160 160">
  <path id="star_path" d="M48.856,22.73c0.983-0.958,1.33-2.364,0.906-3.671c-0.425-1.307-1.532-2.24-2.892-2.438l-12.092-1.757
  c-0.515-0.075-0.96-0.398-1.19-0.865L28.182,3.043c-0.607-1.231-1.839-1.996-3.212-1.996c-1.372,0-2.604,0.765-3.211,1.996
  L16.352,14c-0.23,0.467-0.676,0.79-1.191,0.865L3.069,16.622c-1.359,0.197-2.467,1.131-2.892,2.438
  c-0.424,1.307-0.077,2.713,0.906,3.671l8.749,8.528c0.373,0.364,0.544,0.888,0.456,1.4L8.224,44.701
  c-0.183,1.06,0.095,2.091,0.781,2.904c1.066,1.267,2.927,1.653,4.415,0.871l10.814-5.686c0.452-0.237,1.021-0.235,1.472,0
  l10.815,5.686c0.526,0.277,1.087,0.417,1.666,0.417c1.057,0,2.059-0.47,2.748-1.288c0.687-0.813,0.964-1.846,0.781-2.904
  l-2.065-12.042c-0.088-0.513,0.083-1.036,0.456-1.4L48.856,22.73z"/>

  <circle id="circle" r="2" cx="0" cy="0" fill="tomato"/>
  <animateMotion xlink:href="#circle" dur="10s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite">
    <mpath xlink:href="#star_path"/>
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

Как в реальном времени получать координаты анимированного шарика? 
Вот такой например код показывает постоянно одни и те же координаты.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте [`getBoundClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), вместо `getBBox()`. Метод вернет объект с текущими координатами и размерами.

> Возвращаемое значение — это объект TextRectangle, содержащий свойства только для чтения left, top, right и bottom, описывающие бокс с границами в пиксельном измерении. Значения top и left даются относительно верхнего левого угла порта просмотра.

```js
const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
setInterval(function() {
  const {left, top} = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(`x: ${left}, y: ${top}`);
}, 200);
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 160 160">
  <path id="star_path" d="M48.856,22.73c0.983-0.958,1.33-2.364,0.906-3.671c-0.425-1.307-1.532-2.24-2.892-2.438l-12.092-1.757
  c-0.515-0.075-0.96-0.398-1.19-0.865L28.182,3.043c-0.607-1.231-1.839-1.996-3.212-1.996c-1.372,0-2.604,0.765-3.211,1.996
  L16.352,14c-0.23,0.467-0.676,0.79-1.191,0.865L3.069,16.622c-1.359,0.197-2.467,1.131-2.892,2.438
  c-0.424,1.307-0.077,2.713,0.906,3.671l8.749,8.528c0.373,0.364,0.544,0.888,0.456,1.4L8.224,44.701
  c-0.183,1.06,0.095,2.091,0.781,2.904c1.066,1.267,2.927,1.653,4.415,0.871l10.814-5.686c0.452-0.237,1.021-0.235,1.472,0
  l10.815,5.686c0.526,0.277,1.087,0.417,1.666,0.417c1.057,0,2.059-0.47,2.748-1.288c0.687-0.813,0.964-1.846,0.781-2.904
  l-2.065-12.042c-0.088-0.513,0.083-1.036,0.456-1.4L48.856,22.73z"/>

  <circle id="circle" r="2" cx="0" cy="0" fill="tomato"/>
  <animateMotion xlink:href="#circle" dur="10s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite">
    <mpath xlink:href="#star_path"/>
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

**NOTE**:

`left`/`top` переменные - это значения верхнего левого угла, поэтому если вам нужно вычислить центр круга, тогда придется прибавить к этим координатам половину радиуса круга.

```js
const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
setInterval(function() {
  const {left, top} = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
  const circleR = parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('r'));
  const [circleX, circleY] = [left + circleR / 2, top + circleR / 2];
  console.log(`x: ${circleX}, y: ${circleY}`);
}, 200);
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 160 160">
  <path id="star_path" d="M48.856,22.73c0.983-0.958,1.33-2.364,0.906-3.671c-0.425-1.307-1.532-2.24-2.892-2.438l-12.092-1.757
  c-0.515-0.075-0.96-0.398-1.19-0.865L28.182,3.043c-0.607-1.231-1.839-1.996-3.212-1.996c-1.372,0-2.604,0.765-3.211,1.996
  L16.352,14c-0.23,0.467-0.676,0.79-1.191,0.865L3.069,16.622c-1.359,0.197-2.467,1.131-2.892,2.438
  c-0.424,1.307-0.077,2.713,0.906,3.671l8.749,8.528c0.373,0.364,0.544,0.888,0.456,1.4L8.224,44.701
  c-0.183,1.06,0.095,2.091,0.781,2.904c1.066,1.267,2.927,1.653,4.415,0.871l10.814-5.686c0.452-0.237,1.021-0.235,1.472,0
  l10.815,5.686c0.526,0.277,1.087,0.417,1.666,0.417c1.057,0,2.059-0.47,2.748-1.288c0.687-0.813,0.964-1.846,0.781-2.904
  l-2.065-12.042c-0.088-0.513,0.083-1.036,0.456-1.4L48.856,22.73z"/>

  <circle id="circle" r="2" cx="0" cy="0" fill="tomato"/>
  <animateMotion xlink:href="#circle" dur="10s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite">
    <mpath xlink:href="#star_path"/>
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

**P.S.**

```
const [circleX, circleY] = [left + circleR / 2, top + circleR / 2];
```

Это маленький хак, то же самое что и:

```
const circleX = left + circleR / 2;
const circleY = top + circleR / 2;
```

Comment: Ну что, думаю ответа лучше и не будет, но дождёмся ТС. Если его всё устроит — отдаю баллы вам.